# Formula that deletes filtered results, but if nothing is found, deletes everything

Tags: excel, with-statement, vba

```
Dim rng3 As Range

    Set rng3 = Range("J1").CurrentRegion

    rng3.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    With rng3
        With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Rows.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End With
    End With
```

The above code (in theory) filters on "J1", anything that is other than blank ("<>") and then deletes the results. The problem is if there is already just blank data in column J it deletes everything.

Comment: `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried and tested the following and it does as you expect:

```
Sub foo()
    Set rng3 = Range("J1").CurrentRegion
    rng3.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    With rng3.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            NewAddress = Replace(rng3.Rows.Name, "A$1", "A$2")
            Range(NewAddress).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Or using a different approach:

```
Sub foo2()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row with data on Column A

For i = 2 To LastRow 'Loop from Row 2 to the Last Row with data
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 10).Value <> "" Then Sheet1.Rows(i).Delete 'Check Column J for any value, and if it has a value delete that row
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Good spot! I didn't read on after seeing that `specialcells` wasn't used

Comment: The issue with that you excluded the resize code, is that now the headers are getting deleted which is not ideal...

Comment: @K.Robert Updated my answer to exclude the first row, a little workaround, I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but for now, this will do what you want.

Comment: If there was nothing to delete for it it came up with an error at the NewAddress = Replace(rng3.rows.Name, "A$1", "A$2") line.

Comment: I think I will just bypass this with an on error code, thanks for the help so far :).

Comment: @K.Robert please have a look at my updated answer, it will loop through the rows and if something found on column J then it will delete that row.